# Why I am getting Traceback most recent call last and file string at line 6

Tags: python, random

My python code is below. when I run this code in compiler every single time I'm getting an error like this below.

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    turtle.setup(850, 850)
  File "<string>", line 6, in setup
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3553, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3569, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 458, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1820, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

MY CODE:

```
import random
import turtle

turtle.setup(850, 850)
turtle.penup()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.tracer(0, 0)

x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(1, 16000):
    r = random.uniform(0, 1)

    if r < 0.1:
        nextX = 0
        nextY = float(0.16 * y)

        x = nextX
        y = nextY

    elif r < 0.88:
        nextX = float(0.85 * x * 0.04 * y)
        nextY = float(-0.04 * x * 0.85 * y + 1.6)

        x = nextX
        y = nextY

    elif r < 0.93:
        nextX = float(0.20 * x * -0.26 * y)
        nextY = float(0.23 * x * 0.22 * y + 1.6)

        x = nextX
        y = nextY

    else:
        nextX = float(-0.15 * x * 0.28 * y)
        nextY = float(0.26 * x * 0.24 * y + 0.44)

        x = nextX
        y = nextY    


    turtle.goto(x*40, y*40)
    turtle.dot(2, 'green')

turtle.done()
```

This is one of the undefined error I found for the first time.
How can I fix this? what is wrong in this code. Thank you so much in advance for solving this

Comment: there is no DISPLAY environment variable set. what is your setup? Are you running this on a local Linux PC?

Answer (score 0):

That happens typical, if you start your script on the remote host via ssh as example, because there is no display and the DISPLAY environment variable can not be set. Where do you running your script?

Comment: in online terminal

Comment: I think its a reason